# git pre-merge (via pre-commit) hook to identify if files in a specific directory have changed

Tags: git, github, merge, githooks

I'm looking to create a pre-commit hook which does the following:

- IF the commit is a merge and it is being merged into `master` (this *should* only happen with a PR)

  - IF the user has added or modified any of the files in folder **A**

    - COMPARE the *files* in **A** in the branch being merged into `master` to the files in **A** which are currently in `master` => IF `master` contains any "new" or modified files (relative to the branch being merged into master), REJECT the merge

I have an idea of how I might go about this, but I'm a little confused about a few things:

1. Do I actually want to use the pre-commit hook to do this? Are there docs which identify the args passed to this hook when it's called?
2. Does the hook operate in the context of the branch that's being merged (e.g. if I'm merging branch `foo` into `master`, if I call `git <action>` will that action be run in the context of `foo`)?

Thanks!